# SSRS FORMAT Function by Default Rounding of the Decimal Values to 2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When i Use Format Function by Default value (12.1234) is rounding off to 2 decimal points (12.12)

Below is my Expression

```
=Format(Fields!FEEPERUNIT.Value, "C") & " Rate Per Member "
```

It Gave me `$12.12 Rate Per Member`

I expect my data to be like

```
 My Data | Expected Data
 12.1234 | $12.1234 Rate Per Member
 45.6700 | $45.67 Rate Per Member
 78.00   | $78 Rate Per Member
 901.23  | $901.23 Rate Per Member
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not SSRS's fault, it's the format code you're using.

If you want it always to be accurate to at least 2 decimal places, then use `$0.00##` as the format. This'll return the values below:

```
$12.1234
$45.67
$78.00
$901.23
$11725.50
```

If you *must* return an integer only for those that are integers, you'll need to use an expression instead. For example:

```
IIf(Fields!FEEPERUNIT.Value Mod 1 = 0, "$0", "$0.0###")
```

This'll return the values below:

```
$12.1234
$45.67
$78
$901.23
$11725.5
```

Comment: i tried using your expression it gives me "$0.0###" all the time .

Comment: I *assume* you put that inside your `FORMAT` expression, @Mahesh.K ? Also, if every row has that value,that implies you have no rows with a integer value.

Comment: No , i simply used your expression instead of mine . i just tried with single record i.e 12.1234

Comment: You need to replace the `"C"` @Mahesh.K not the whole thing.

Comment: You mean this is the final expression `Format(Fields!FEEPERUNIT.Value, IIf(Fields!FEEPERUNIT.Value Mod 1 = 0, "$0", "$0.0###"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Larnu for responding . I've achieved it with below expression . i removed Format Function and concatenating the `$` symbol manually to the existing Amounts.

```
"$" & Fields!FEEPERUNIT.Value &  " Rate Per Member "
```

Comment: So wait, `Fields!FEEPERUNIT.Value` isn't a numerical datatype? That's the problem...